# SharePoint Usage for Academic Files

Tags: storage

I would like to know if SharePoint is the best solution for Academic Files (over 3,000 and growing). We currently have them packed tight in file cabinets, overflowing in boxes, and they continue to double every year.

We want to know what the best online platform would be to safely house these records. We would like to move to an all online storage and access system, as there are too many to continue having paper files.

Any comments or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint supports libraries of up to 30 million documents so that would provide some room to double for a while :)  It also supports security, auditing, check in/out, approvals, custom workflows, IRM and document retention, among other things.

Good scanning/OCR software will also help you not only get that data into SharePoint but also with full text so that it can be searched and indexed.  We use [Abbyy](http://www.abbyy.com/solutions/sharepoint/) for this but I really don't know much more than the plants that use it love it.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by saying that your requirement is a little too broad. Yes, indeed SharePoint is a great (greatest if you ask me!) Enterprise Content Management tool (Records Management, Document Management and Web Content Management - all accompagned by a lot of Business Intelligence, Social, Workflows and extreme extensibility by some of the richest API on the market - surpasses .NET all together). But, in your case you would need to formalize what exactly are you looking for, because the way I see it digitizing existing content is your main concern (if you only have paper version of your content) - and this simply leads to the biggest question, every single ECM will have for starters - "How would you manage the in-flow of content?".

Practically, this means scannning, clasifying, tagging, etc. Then, the actual business continuity, plus proper architecture, etc. - do not go in without help, and only go in after you did your homework - map out your requirements to the lowest detail possible, and ask solution providers for the Pros/Cons on other technologies - you need to consider what infrastructure you have, and what IT strategies are already in place!

Already, some case studies on MSDN/TechNET for schools already adopting SharePoint - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285756(v=office.14).aspx or http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335971(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: And too add, Sharepoint has a rich vendor ecosystem, so if in your analysis you do decide Sharepoint is the right system to handle your document storage needs, there are folks like Knowledgelake who sell add ons specifically for handling document inflow from scanning.

Comment: +1 for providing schools case studies, I was looking for them, Thanks